# How can I get child data when Lazyloading is not enabled using Entity Framework 5?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework and I would like to find out how to get data from a class and a child of the class. Here is my setup:

```
 public class Question
 {
    public Question()
    {
        this.Answers = new List<Answer>();
    } 
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    ...
    ...
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}

public class Answer
{
    public int AnswerId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
}
```

I have set the following as I don't want Lazyloading for all the other classes:

```
DbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
    public IList<Question> GetQuestions(int subTopicId, int questionStatusId)
    {
        var questions = _questionsRepository.GetAll()
            .Where(a => a.SubTopicId == subTopicId &&
                        a.QuestionStatusId == questionStatusId)
            .ToList();
        return questions; 
    }
```

My repository looks like this:

```
    public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return DbSet;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding **.Include("path")** before .ToList();

```
public IList<Question> GetQuestions(int subTopicId, int questionStatusId)
{
    var questions = _questionsRepository.GetAll()
        .Where(a => a.SubTopicId == subTopicId &&
                    a.QuestionStatusId == questionStatusId)
        .Include("...")
        .ToList();
    return questions; 
}
```

Comment: Do I just put the word "predicate" or should that be the property name? What about if there is more than one child?

Comment: The property name. You can add as many .Include() as you want. Just see the property from within the standard (start) class. Ex.: .Include("foo").Include("foo.bar") -> bar is a property in class foo and foo is a property in the class you are getting from the database.

Answer (score 3):

You can eager load multiple levels by using `.Include()` in your `DbQuery` or explicitly lazy load by calling `.Load()` on the `DbEntityEntry.Collection` or `DbEntityEntry.Reference`.

Example

```
context.MyParentEntities.Include(x=>x.ChildEntities); //eager load

//explicit collection property lazy load
context.Entry(MyEntity).Collection(x=>x.ChildEntities).Load();
//explicit reference property lazy load
context.Entry(MyEntity).Reference(x=>x.ChildEntity).Load();
```

Here is a useful guide : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232

Comment: I gave you an upvote. I guess the downvoter is too shy to answer.